# Contratiempo con los host virtuales

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, cree un host virtual para tener más facilidades para manejar un proyecto llamado "bolsa".

Tengo este código en C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1      bolsa.com
```

Actualmente he creado un nuevo proyecto llamado "zoo". Se supone que nada más crearlo, puedo acceder a el con "localhost/zoo/public", pero...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y de hecho, me encuentro que si pongo de url solo 'localhost', me lleva al proyecto ***bolsa***.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como hago para arreglarlo?

Más datos: Este es el contenido del fichero C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
##NameVirtualHost *:80
#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ##ServerName or ##ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>

##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/bolsa/public/"
 ServerName mipaginaweb.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Al final se observa el host virtual y su ruta.
La historia es como hacer que esto no se pise con mi nuevo proyecto.

Edito: Actualmente tengo esto en el fichero C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts:

```
127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.0.1      bolsa.com
```

Y lo siguiente en el fichero C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<Directory c:/xampp/htdocs>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/bolsa/public/"
    ServerName mipaginaweb.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Pero mi problema continua.

Comment: intenta quitanto las comillas de "C:/xampp/htdocs/bolsa/public/"

Comment: Así he hecho. De repente bolsa.com no funciona, pero el modo localhost se ha recuperado. Esto es algo caotico, pero he logrado arreglarme por ahora, a ver si esto va bien.

Answer (score 1):

Para iniciar en tu archivo `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` debe de tener siempre localhost como predeterminado, luego puedes añadir mas **host**
**EJ:**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       myproyecto.dev
```

En tu caso solo tienes uno lo cual puede estar ocasionando el problema.

Posterior  en el archivo `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` debes de tener una configuracion de localhost, una para la direccion de proyectos y despues recien una de tu proyecto

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<Directory c:/xampp/htdocs>
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/myproyecto/public
    ServerName myproyecto.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Posteriormente tu puedes ingresar a tu proyecto por la url `myproyecto.dev`

Comment: Así he hecho, aunque no ha funcionado. He actualizado mi pregunta para explicar mi nueva situación.

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como comentan arriba esta bien solo que falta agragar 
`NameVirtualHost *:80` al inicio de cada etiqueda virualhost en mi caso quedo de la siguiente forma

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName cursolaravel1.com
    ServerAlias www.cursolaravel1.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/probando-laravel/public"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/probando-laravel/public">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Espero y aun sea de ayuda