# VirtualHost con Laravel y Xampp

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, virtualhost

tengo una consulta al momento de configurar el virtual host con un proyecto de laravel cada que pongo localhost me redirecciona al proyecto de laravel, y si quisiera cambiar a otro que esta en mi carpeta htdocs no me permite y queria saber si cada vez que quiera hacer eso tengo que desactivar el virtual host o tengo algo mal configurado

asi tengo el virtualhost

```
#VHost Curso Laravel
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName cursolaravel1.com.devel
    ServerAlias www.cursolaravel1.com.devel
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/probando-laravel/public"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/probando-laravel/public">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

y en System32/etc en el archivo host esta asi

```
127.0.0.1           cursolaravel1.com.devel
```

Si comento el virtualhost sin problemas puedo acceder a mas proyectos pero al activerlos solo me deja navegar en el de laravel aunque ponga "localhost/otroproyecto"

Comment: tal ves eso te pueda servir -->> https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166057/contratiempo-con-los-host-virtuales/166118#166118

Comment: Ya quedo arreglado el localhost como siempre, ahor el problema es que en mi proyecto de laravel ingresando con "cursolaravel1.com" me manda al dashboard de localhost